# WP E-Commerce + Static Page Content = Wont Work Together

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I am having a problem with permalinks to staic pages, and wp-e commerce.

I have 2 types of content:
1) Pages that are static and use unique templates, published as pages, organized into menus.
2) Posts that are generated by the wp e-commerce plugin, published as posts, organized via wp-ecommerce templates.

Here is the Series of events I am dealing with(I am starting to hate wp e-commerce)

1. Staic Pages give me a 404 Error
2. I disable WP E-Commerce
3. Static pages ALL display the same default homepage template
4. I update any static page content(just press the update button)
5. All static pages are showing now.
6. I make ANY change in the wp dashboard and we're back at step 1.

Can anyone make any sense of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I could not find a way to do this and keep my url decent. I ended up just going with the regular permalink structure. It works, but is not ideal.

Thanks for everyone's input.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Wordpress Documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks),

> If you've tried to navigate to a newly created Page and encounter an
>   error, you likely need to update your Permalink structure. Remember,
>   each time you add a new static Page to WordPress, new rules must be
>   generated and updated to .htaccess (WordPress 1.X) or to the internal
>   rewrites array (WordPress 2.X).

Please also note that it is not advised to start your permalinks with tags like `%postname%`, `%category%`, or other text-based tags as it can really decrease performance as you have more posts.

Comment: Thanks Kelly, I appreciate the input... I've been spinning my wheels on this all day. I understand that its not good to use this convention for permalinks.

All of these pages are already created.. They're not new. 
When you say new rules must be generated do you mean that I need to update the permalink structure?

Comment: Sidenote: When I use the /%date%/%postname%/ it doesnt make a difference, I am still getting 'page not found error'

Comment: Looked into it a bit -- try simply clicking "Save Changes" on the "Permalinks" page when the WP E-commerce plugin is enabled. If it can't update your .htaccess file, do that manually with the newly generated code that will display.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it Kelly. I can get in to my .htaccess file and edit, but I am not sure what code I am adding to it, or where to do it. I've never edited that file before on a site. 

Sorry, I am not a strong back-end programmer

Comment: You shouldn't have to write any of the code by hand. Wordpress's built-in "Permalinks" page should take care of it for you. Just copy & paste the whole block and replace your whole .htaccess file.